# Storing mail in database, data type

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, datatypes

I've found pretty poor informations about mail databases.

My need is to archive mail messages downloaded from a normal pop3 or imap account: I am an ordinary user and I do not own the server, but just the mailbox. So I should exclude solutions like dbmail, suggested in [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82891/saving-all-incoming-messages-into-a-database-with-postfix).

Two questions:

1) can MySQL be used for this purpose?

2) If yes, which is the best data type to be used for the column which will contain the **body** of the mail? It can include attachments (represented as sequences of characters, as you know) and its length is definitely unpredictable: it may vary from a few bytes to several MiB and it should not impose a (small) upper limit to the design. It should have a decent performance, if exists.

In brief: which is the most common approach when handling this kind of data with a MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find out if "mail" guarantees that all data is utf8 or ascii or whatever.  If utf8, then use

```
MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

for a limit of 16MB.  For a 4GB limit, change to `LONGTEXT`.

If the mail is not forced into some character encoding, then use

```
MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB
```

(without a charset).